# How to find out the port on which my PowerShell script is communicating to the other server?

Tags: windows, powershell, connection, port

I have a PowerShell script which copies certain files from a remote server and pastes in the local server. Now I need to use the file from another agent server which doesn't have connectivity to the remote server.

So I need to find out the port on which the communication will be established to the remote server from the agent server to copy the data.

I tried using netstat command but didn't find anything in that.

What are the steps to be followed to get the port information?

Comment: How are you copying files which has connectivity?

Comment: Depends on the method of copy, please show us the code you're using to copy the files

Comment: Hi @CodeRunner, I got the connection was established on port microsoft-ds port. I got it using netstat command. Also, I have enabled port 445 which is microsoft-ds port and I am able to telnet the remote server on port 445. Please help.

Comment: @MiteshAgrawal what method you are using for file copying windows file share/FTP/SFTP ??